# time.sleep() has 60 sec limit in plpythonu?

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, plpython

Note: I'm running Postgres 11.7 and Python 2.7.17.

It appears that `time.sleep()` has 60 sec limit in plpythonu function. It works as expected up to 60 seconds. But if passed a value greater than 60 then it stops at 60 seconds.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_sleep(interval_str INTERVAL)
    RETURNS INTERVAL
AS $$
    try:
        import time
        import datetime

        start_time = time.time()
        t = datetime.datetime.strptime(interval_str,"%H:%M:%S")
        tdelta = datetime.timedelta(hours=t.hour, minutes=t.minute, seconds=t.second)
        interval_secs = tdelta.total_seconds()
        print 'interval_secs=%s' % repr(interval_secs)
        time.sleep(interval_secs)
        elapsed_secs = time.time() - start_time
        return datetime.timedelta(seconds=elapsed_secs)
    except:
        import traceback
        print traceback.format_exc()
        raise
$$ LANGUAGE PLPYTHONU;
```

Here's a test on command line using psql. The first test runs as expected. I told it to sleep for two seconds and it dis. The second test only sleeps for 60 seconds even though I requested a sleep for 120 seconds.

```
$ echo "select now(), test_sleep('2 sec'); select now();" | psql
             now              |   test_sleep
------------------------------+-----------------
 2021-05-07 11:10:27.63041-04 | 00:00:02.005745
(1 row)

              now
-------------------------------
 2021-05-07 11:10:29.652542-04
(1 row)

$ echo "select now(), test_sleep('2 min'); select now();" | psql
              now              |   test_sleep
-------------------------------+-----------------
 2021-05-07 11:10:36.056578-04 | 00:00:59.977787
(1 row)

              now
-------------------------------
 2021-05-07 11:11:36.050637-04
(1 row)

$
```

Here's output from the Postgres log file.

```
interval_secs=2.0
interval_secs=120.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not unexpected (although I can't reliably reproduce it).

https://realpython.com/python-sleep/

> Note: In Python 3.5, the core developers changed the behavior of
> time.sleep() slightly. The new Python sleep() system call will last at
> least the number of seconds you’ve specified, even if the sleep is
> interrupted by a signal. This does not apply if the signal itself
> raises an exception, however.

So in python2, time.sleep can return early if interrupted by a signal.  If you don't like that, have it loop to sleep again for the remainder of the time.

Comment: Yes, I'm looping now as a work around. If you can't reproduce it then I will caulk it up to something odd in my build. Thanks.